# How to fetch JSON data from a url using URLSession?

Tags: ios, json, swift, nsurlsession

I am working on an iOS application in which I have to fetch data from [this url](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/2iodh4vg0eortkl/facts.json) .

As I can see this url contain JSON data so here should I need to parse it or not I am not getting it how to get this JSON data.

Here is my code.

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON

typealias ServiceResponse = (ApiResponseData, NSError?) -> Void

class ApiManager: NSObject {

    var session:URLSession? = nil
    var urlRequest:URLRequest? = nil

    override init(){
        super.init()

        urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string:"https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/2iodh4vg0eortkl/facts.json")!)
        urlRequest?.addValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        session = URLSession(configuration: .default)

    }

    func callRestApiToFetchDetails(onCompletion: @escaping ServiceResponse) {
        let task = session?.dataTask(with: urlRequest!, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
            print("Response = \(data)")

            do {
                let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
                // Do Stuff
                print("\(jsonData)")
            } catch {
                // handle error
            print("Error in parsing - \(error)")
            }
        })
        task?.resume()
    }
}
```

But I am getting error in parsing.

[image]

Comment: try to print the error in the try catch block `} catch (let error) { print("Error in parsing - \(error)")`

Comment: @lufritz there's no need for the `(let error)` part, the `catch` block automatically creates an `error` variable, so you can just do `catch { print(error)}

Comment: Unrelated, but there are several conceptual issues with your code. Don't initialize values as optionals if you will definitely assign a non-optional value to them in the initializer. Moreover, there's no need to assign hardcoded values inside an initializer, this is not Obj-C, in Swift you can assign objects to variables as well outside the initializer. There's also no need to inherit from `NSObject`, in Swift classes don't need to have a base class.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I am new in Swift. Can you please help to parse this JSON response. I have updated question.

Comment: @ajeetsharma also, if you want to use the SwiftyJSON framework (instead of which I'd recommend using the `Codable` protocol in Swift 4), why don't you use its methods for decoding the JSON response?

Comment: @DávidPásztor How to use SwifyJSON ? Actually I tried using cocoapods and I added this framework but I was facing same issue in SwiftyJSON.

Comment: _How to use SwifyJSON ?_ That's not an off-topic question here on SO and definitely not a question that could or should be answered in comments. It seems like you are lacking the basics of Swift, so I'd recommend reading the [Swift book](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/book/the-swift-programming-language-swift-4/id881256329?mt=11) or the [Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html) online documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You web service response is `String.Encoding.ascii` that convert into 
`String.Encoding.utf8` after you have to convert through 
`NSDictionary` `JSONSerialization`.

Try this method to work.

```
  let url = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/2iodh4vg0eortkl/facts.json"
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!) { (data, res, err) in

        if let d = data {
            if let value = String(data: d, encoding: String.Encoding.ascii) {

                if let jsonData = value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
                    do {
                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: []) as! [String: Any]

                        if let arr = json["rows"] as? [[String: Any]] {
                            debugPrint(arr)
                        }

                    } catch {
                        NSLog("ERROR \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        }.resume()
```

Comment: It is working, but is there any other simple way we can parse this. Is it possible to more short code for it ?

Comment: Don't use `NSDictionary` in Swift and don't call the `init` method explicitly.

Comment: Also don't use `.mutableLeaves` as it has no meaning in `Swift`. You control the mutability using the `let` or `var` keywords when declaring the variable.

Comment: You can use [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON). and my answer is right then right tick mart or up point. thanks.

Comment: Must read [NSJSONSerialization Fails with Unicode](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/65676) same issues in this apple forums. Seems to be the server side problem. JSON needs to be encoded in UTF-8, but your server seems to be sending it in other encoding