# Getting Data from JSON Swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift

Can Anyone Help me with this

my data after parsing a JSON URL is

```
{
    AREA =     (
                {
            "area_name" = "Bhaktamadhu Nagar";
            "city_id" = 4;
            id = 31;
            price = "100.00";
        },
                {
            "area_name" = "Gandamunda";
            "city_id" = 4;
            id = 32;
            price = "100.00";
        }
);
}
```

and there is a lot more.

I want to fetch only `area_name` and `price` values in an array

my code is something like that

```
do { 
let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableLeaves) as! NSDictionary
print(parsedData)}
```

I am getting my Upper format in the `parsedData`

What is the exact code for getting my `area_name` and `price` which should store in two separate arrays as `aname[]` and `price[]`

Please don't mark it as a duplicate already searched a lot before posting this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `JSON` data is converted into `[String: AnyObject]`.

AREA data is `[[String: AnyObject]]` so create a `[String: AnyObject]` array. and getting a one by one value from array.

[How to fetch JSON data from a url using URLSession?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47730275/6822622)

try this code. it's helpfull

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

        if let jsonData = data {
            do {
                let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: .mutableLeaves) as! [String: AnyObject]
                if let area = parsedData["AREA"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                    for a in area {
                        areaNameArr.append(a["area_name"])
                        priceArr.append(a["price"])
                        print(a)

                    }
                }
            }
            catch let error {
                debugPrint(error)
            }
        }
        else {
            debugPrint(error as Any)
        }

    }.resume()
```

Comment: I am getting this error now: --- Editor placeholder in the source file in both the print statement.

Comment: Is data printing or not in debug console?

Comment: No, while writing the code only this error is there

Comment: How Can I @AshvinGudaliya

Comment: Now  I have found the values in my console but not in array please help me?

Answer (score -1):

Use the [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) Lib.

It’s easy and fast.

I am using it and it’s very helpful in this way:

```js
let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.ephemeral)

    self.Task = session.dataTask(with: RequestLink as URLRequest , completionHandler: { (data,response,error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error as Any)
        }

        let ReadJson4Rest = JSON(data: data!)
        if let Rest_Details = ReadJson4Rest["Result"].array{
            for Details in Rest_Details {

                let Comment  =  Details.dictionaryValue["Comment"]!
                let UserName =  Details.dictionaryValue["User_ID"]!

                if Comment != nil {

                    let FirstChar = UserName.description.characters.first
                    self.GetUserImage(UserName: UserName.string! ,AlphabetCat: (FirstChar?.description)!)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.CommentValue.append(Comment.string!)
                        self.UserNames.append(UserName.string!)
                        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "Load"), object: nil)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
    self.Task?.resume() 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this I will do that.